# Repetitive Initialization in Python for Loops

Tags: python, for-loop, initialization

UPDATED to correct errors and clarify --

I want to restructure a list of dictionaries such that every time 'series' changes a new document is created. Is there a way to avoid this ugliness:

```
rows = [
    {'series': 'Series A', 'model_number': 'x', 'spec 1': 1, 'spec 2': 2},
    {'series': 'Series A', 'model_number': 'y', 'spec 1': 0.1, 'spec 2': 0.2},
    {'series': 'Series B', 'model_number': 'z','spec 1': 10, 'spec 2': 20},
]

def func(rows):
    documents = []
    models_data = []
    model_data = {}
    last_series = None
    for row in rows:
        if row['series'] != last_series: # signifying a new document 
            if models_data:  
                document = {'series': last_series, 'data': models_data}
                documents.append(document.copy())
            last_series = row['series']
            models_data = []
            model_data = {}

        model_data['model_number'] = row['model_number']
        for k, v in row.items():
            if k != 'series' and k != 'model_data':
                if v:
                    model_data[k] = v
        models_data.append(model_data.copy())

    if models_data:
        document = {'series': last_series, 'data': models_data}
        documents.append(document.copy())

    return documents
```

which returns:

```
[{'series': 'Series A', 'data': 
    [{'model_number': 'x', 'spec 1': 1, 'spec 2': 2}, 
    {'model_number': 'y', 'spec 1': 0.1, 'spec 2': 0.2}]}, 

{'series': 'Series B', 'data': 
    [{'model_number': 'z', 'spec 1': 10, 'spec 2': 20}]}]
```

? In particular, avoiding initializing data structures in two places; plus the repetitive assignment after the loop terminates. Assume `rows` is a list of dictionaries from a CSV file, e.g.

Additionally, is there a dictionary-like object that behaves like a primitive in the sense assigning to it automatically makes a copy? A missed `.copy()` leads to a debugging nightmare.

By the same token, within a class can one avoid:

```
try:
     foo = self.attribute
except AttributeError:
     self.attribute = self.get_foo()
```

?

Comment: Would help if you could provide a little `rows` example to work with. And code that doesn't have a syntax error.

Comment: In the `for k, v in row.items()` loop, it adds a copy of the data dict to the document for every key, in the row? So if you had `row = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}` you'd end up with `{'a':1}, {'a':1, 'b':2}, {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}` appended to the document?

Comment: It may also help if you elaborated on what this is supposed to do.

Comment: First problem I can spot is that if you're not using an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) you may be getting items in an order you're not expecting.

Comment: There were a number of errors, fixed. Should have used my a tested example. To be clear, order does not matter. I am taking CSV data (a list of dicts) and splitting it into JSON documents whenever series changes. I hate repeat initialization, and I hate the explicit .copy() method--I get `dict` is supposed to behave like a regular class, but it seems counterintuitive to me. I want to pass the minted dict into another data structure then reuse the variable name in my loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to give some unexpected results (after fixing the errors), because it treats the first case differently than the others.  For example:

```
>>> rows = [{"id": i//4, "other": i} for i in range(12)]
>>> func(rows)
[{None: [{'other': 1}]}, {0: [{'other': 2}, {'other': 3}]}, 
 {1: [{'other': 4}, {'other': 5}, {'other': 6}, {'other': 7}]}, 
 {2: [{'other': 8}, {'other': 9}, {'other': 10}, {'other': 11}]}]
```

doesn't seem like it's what you want.  You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to get a more consistent (IMO) version of this, though:

```
from itertools import groupby

def newfunc(rows, key_on):
    grouped = groupby(rows, key=lambda row: row[key_on])
    for groupkey, group in grouped:
        newgroup = [{k: v for k,v in d.items() if k != key_on}
                    for d in group]
        yield {groupkey: newgroup}
```

gives

```
>>> list(newfunc(rows, "id"))
[{0: [{'other': 0}, {'other': 1}, {'other': 2}, {'other': 3}]}, 
 {1: [{'other': 4}, {'other': 5}, {'other': 6}, {'other': 7}]}, 
 {2: [{'other': 8}, {'other': 9}, {'other': 10}, {'other': 11}]}]
```